# Getting too few arguments error when calling format.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, render, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this controller method

```
  def import_matching_objects
    matching_objects = objectTime.find_by_name_and_hometown_and_age(current_user)
    matching_objects.each do |object_time|
      user_object_time_match = UserObjectTimeMatch.new(:user_id => user.id,
                                                 :object_time_id => object_time.id,
                                                 :matches => true)
      # Save objects
      if !user_object_time_match.save_and_create_object_time
        puts "Failed to save user object: #{user_object_time_match.errors.full_messages}" 
      end 
    end 
    format.js { render js: "window.location='/objects/index'" } 
  end
```

but its producing this error

```
ArgumentError (too few arguments):

app/controllers/user_object_time_matches_controller.rb:31:in `format'
```

on the line "format.js { render js: "window.location='/objects/index'" } ".  My syntax seems consistent with every example I've found online.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `respond_to` block should resolve the `ArgumentError (too few arguments)` problem:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: "window.location='/objects/index'" }   
end
```